# The character '<' '>' cannot be used in an attribute value of XML

Tags: xml, velocity

Now I'm trying to generating XML file from class files using ***Velocity Template***.
In class file,

```
public List<String> temp(String str, List<String>) {
    ......
}
```

---

I want to generate XML file with this format.

```
<jar name="JAR2">
    <signature>
        <class name=" JAR2.AA.EE.Class B ">
            <method name="temp" type=" java.util.List<java.lang.String> ">
                <parameter type="java.lang.Integer" />
                <parameter type="java.util.List<java.lang.String>" />
            </method>
       </class>
    </signature>
</jar>
```

My problem is ***The character '<' '>' cannot be used in an attribute value.***
I want to allow these characters '<' '>' in my XML file. I want to know add property in **Velocity Engine.**
Please give me ideas. Thank you!

Comment: How would this method look? `public <T> List<? extends T> temp(T str, List<? super T>)`

Comment: Right, it can't be. Escape it.

Comment: I think my question isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to use invalidates the syntax of XML.

Instead, you must encode these special characters with their (almost) HTML equivalent.

In your case, they will be:

`&lt;` for `<`; and `&gt;` for `>`.

Comment: Upvoted, though strictly speaking XML and HTML don't use the same character entity reference codes - see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not valid XML. Think about some other way to encode it.

Maybe

```
<method name="temp" type="java.util.List" genericTypes="java.lang.String">
```

or

```
<method name="temp" type="java.util.List[java.lang.String]">
```

I suppose you could also encode the `<` directly as `&lt;`.

Comment: Thank for your advice! But I want to allow these characters '<' '>' in my xml. I don't know how to set property in velocity engine. Now, I think I got it.                                                                 ve.addProperty("eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class",
                "org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.EscapeXmlReference");
        ve.setProperty("eventhandler.escape.xml.match",
                "/^\\$([^_\\{].*|\\{[^_].*\\})$/");

Answer (score 0):

I think my question wasn't clear. I got it with this code. Thank you!

```
ve.addProperty("eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class",
                    "org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.EscapeXmlReference");
    ve.setProperty("eventhandler.escape.xml.match",
                    "/^\\$([^_\\{].*|\\{[^_].*\\})$/");
```